# Sending request from tcp client to server with spring integration and receiving data from stored procedure

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I'm a new in Spring Integration framework and want to realize some scheme.

```
Spring Tcp client -> Spring Tcp Server -> Database
```

Several clients periodically send their configuration and receive information from the database in response. The server contains some logic by calling several stored procedures in sequence. For example, the data from the DB cursor can be input parameters to another stored procedure.

Help me please, Is this framework suitable for such tasks ?

Do I understand correctly that I need to implement a TCP gateway in the client, a TCP gateway and a JDBC gateway in the server ?

And maybe you can tell what difficulties I will have to face with such an implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Integration with its loosely-coupled architecture based on messaging is really suitable for any tasks. Plus luckily there are already out-of-the-box components to help you to build the solution. And you are really on the right track: to send request and receive replies over TCP/IP you indeed need the pair of those gateways:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/ip.html#tcp-gateways

And yes, the `StoredProcOutboundGateway` is exactly for use-case where we would like to perform some RDBMS stored procedure and get some result from there:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/jdbc.html#stored-procedure-outbound-gateway

I don't see a reason, though, in calling several procedures sequentially from the application, where we can simply do that on DB side with one procedure all together.

Comment: thanks for you quick answer ! Perhaps you could suggest how to call several procedures through the same gateway. I have seen in the documentation about BeanPropertySqlParameterSourceFactory using payload as input parameters to a procedure. But what about mapping, If I need different RowMapper ? Or should I create multiple StoredProcExecutor beans and pass them to the StoredProcOutboundGateway ?

Comment: I see what you mean, but no: even if we can determine the procedure at runtime against request message, we still cannot have dynamic `RowMapper`. You have to create several `StoredProcOutboundGateway`  service activators.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try!
There are many unclear points for me.